# Creating a balanced binary tree from an array, trying to do it literately but keeps creating an unbalanced tree?

Tags: java, arrays, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

The getAlphabet() is an array of the alphabet from a-z. I'm trying to get the tree filled from the array in level order. So root is a, children are b,c. Then b children are d,e?

```
public static void makeTree(String[] alphabet){

    TreeNode<String> root0 = new TreeNode<String>(null);
    TreeNode<String> tempRoot = root0;
    TreeNode<String> tempRoot1 = root0;

    for(int i = 0; i<getAlphabet().length; i++){
        if(2*i+1 < getAlphabet().length-1) {
            tempRoot.setLeftChild(new TreeNode<String>(getAlphabet()[2 * i + 1], tempRoot));
            tempRoot.setRightChild(new TreeNode<String>(getAlphabet()[2 * (i + 1)], tempRoot));

            tempRoot = tempRoot.getLeftChild();
            tempRoot1 = tempRoot.getRightChild();
        }


    }





    // create the Tree as a linked structure from the arrayS myStringChars
    // the Strings are stored using the representation for trees as arrays in the book
    // (e.g. for an element i, the left child is stored in position 2*i + 1, right child is
}
```

Comment: That feels rather unbalanced by definition, like a linked list to the right with one left child per node.  How are you expecting the algorithm to improve on it?

Comment: Inserting them in the order you said will be unbalanced. Really you need to balance the tree after each insertion, pivoting the tree so it has a new root. Inserting them a b c ... z will end in a linked list!

Comment: For a small example, if you add a first it becomes the root. Add b second, root.right is b. The tree is still balanced. Add c third, root.right.right is c. The tree is now unbalanced. To balance it, b needs to be the root and root.left set to the old root (a). The tree is then balanced again.

Comment: @d.j.brown so how would this lead to creating a level order tree? A needs to be the top root node